# Not able to set transparent background for Popup Window Activity

Tags: android, kotlin, popupwindow

I am following [this](https://johncodeos.com/how-to-create-a-popup-window-in-android-using-kotlin/) particular example to create a popup window activity but when I click on a button to open this activity, the background is not semi-transparent as mentioned in the example. I am new to android kotlin development so I am not able to figure this out on my own. Let me know what I am doing wrong.

[image: This is what I am getting (background is not transparent)]

EDIT: This [link](https://android--code.blogspot.com/2018/02/android-kotlin-popup-window-example.html) tells a different method but working fine.

Comment: Show us the code ...

Comment: The root `ConstraintLayout` semi-transparent color with Alpha as 100 is not working. Have you double check your code with his?

Comment: @PraveenSP Code is completely the same as given in the link. If you still want, I can put the code and update the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the translucent theme of your activity, in your "AndroidManifest.xml" file.

```
<activity
        android:name=".ui.PopUpWindow"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme_translucent" />
```

and in your "styles.xml" file.

```
<style name="AppTheme_translucent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Can you make only certain areas of your window translucent?

Answer (score 0):

I travel the code and did not see `setContentView()` method for `PopupWindow` activity. Please set content view for the activity by calling the method inside  PopupWindow's `onCreate()`